# Print first, penultimate and last fields in CSV file

Tags: csv, unix, command, cut

I have big comma separated file with 20000 row and five column, I want to extract particular column, but there are more values so more comma, except header, so how to cut such column.

example file:

```
name,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5
as,"10,12,15",21,"12,11,10,12",5,7
bs,"11,15,16",24,"19,15,18,23",9,3
```

This is my desired output:

```
name,v4,v5
as,5,7
bs,9,3
```

I tried following cut command but doesn't work

```
cut -d, -f1,5,6
```

Comment: 20000 isn't big. Over twenty years ago already, I wouldn't have thought twice about popping that into a text editor and doing search replace on it.

Comment: By my count, your file has six fields: name and v1 through v5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for these scenarios is best to use a proper csv parser. You can find those in Python, for example.

However, since your data seems to have fields with commas just in the very beginning, you can decide to print the first field and then the penultimate and last one:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1, $(NF-1), $NF}' file
name,v4,v5
as,5,7
bs,9,3
```

Comment: Thanks fedorqui, but if I want to cut centre collum (i.e 3rd), then what?

Comment: @mona then you have to use a CSV parser, because bash scripting cannot handle it in a nice way.

Answer (score 0):

In [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp:

```
$ txr extract.tl < data
name,v4,v5
as,5,7
bs,9,3
```

Code in `extract.tl`:

```
(mapdo
  (lambda (line)
    (let ((f (tok-str line #/"[^"]*"|[^,]+/)))
      (put-line `@[f 0],@[f 4],@[f 5]`)))
  (get-lines))
```

As a condensed one liner:

```
$ txr -t '(mapcar* (do let ((f (tok-str @1 #/"[^"]*"|[^,]+/)))
                     `@[f 0],@[f 4],@[f 5]`) (get-lines))' < data
```